# Storing different objects in same variable

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to figure out how i could store different objects in a certain "namespace".

I have something like this:

**app.js**

```
// This is the startup script:
var MyApp = {}
MyApp.ui = {}
MyApp.ui = require('ui/MainWindow');
MyApp.ui = require('ui/SecondWindow');

// Doesn't exist anymore because the 2nd require overwrites the
// first include
MyApp.ui.MainWindow.test;
```

Then i also have `MainWindow.js` and `SecondWindow.js`, which looks like this:

```
var MainWindow = {
    test: "Main"
}

exports.MainWindow = MainWindow;
```

---

```
var SecondWindow = {
    test: "Second"
}

exports.SecondWindow = SecondWindow;
```

The `exports.XXXWindow = XXXWindow` basically makes that object available.

So in my `app.js` i try to store the `MainWindow` object in `MyApp.ui`. So i can call it like this:

`MyApp.ui.MainWindow.test`

Then i'd also like to add the `SecondWindow` object to that. So i can call that in the same way:

`MyApp.ui.SecondWindow.test`

But the way i have it now causes the second require to overwrite the first one. So it now only points to `SecondWindow`. What do i have to do so that i can call both objects from `MyApp.ui` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to do (I'm sorry if code is not syntactically correct but I use coffeescript and I'm not used anymore to Javascript):

**`MainWindow.js`**

```
var MainWindow = function() {
    return {test: 'Main'};
};
module.exports = MainWindow;
```

**`SecondWindow.js`**

```
var SecondWindow = function() {
    return {test: 'Second'};
};
module.exports = SecondWindow;
```

**`app.js`**

```
var myApp = {
    ui: {
        MainWindow: require('MainWindow.js'),
        SecondWindow: require(SecondWindow.js)
    }
};
```

Now my personal opinion. I prefer to do:

**`app.js`**

```
var MainWindow = require('MainWindow'),
    SecondWindow = require('SecondWindow'),
    myApp = {
        ui: {
            MainWindow: new MainWindow(),
            SecondWindow: new SecondWindow()
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The second assignment of `MyApp.ui` will overwrite its old value. However, you could do the following:

```
function inject(obj_into,obj_from){
    for(var x in obj_from)
        obj_into[x] = obj_from[x];
}

MyApp.ui = {MainWindow:{},SecondWindow:{}};
inject(MyApp.ui.MainWindow,require('ui/MainWindow'));
inject(MyApp.ui.SecondWindow,require('ui/SecondWindow'));
```

You first initialize `MyApp.ui` with empty property objects `MainWindow`,`SecondWindow` and fill them with `inject`.